# Itext : set zoom level of external hyper link in pdf

Tags: java, itext, itextpdf

I am using following code to set **external hyperlink** using `itext` library in Java.

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Click to Open File");

PdfAction action = new PdfAction("externalfile.pdf");
action.put(PdfName.NEWWINDOW, PdfBoolean.PDFTRUE);
action.put(PdfName.ZOOM, PdfName.FIT);
chunk.setAction(action);
```

I want to set zoom level of external hyper link: when I click on hyper link file should be open and **FIT** page.

I tried using `action.put(PdfName.ZOOM, PdfName.FIT);` but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please *don't ever* create PDF object *manually* without consulting ISO-32000-1.

You want to create a **GoToR** action. Such an action is expressed as a PDF dictionary that can contain the following keys:

[image: ISO-32000-1 Table 200]

There is *no key named* **Zoom** in that table, hence your code is wrong.

You need the **D** key and as you want to link to a page and define a zoom factor, you need to define a destination:

[image: ISO-32000-1 Table 151]

In other words, the destination needs to be a `PdfArray`! `PdfName.FIT` isn't sufficient!

(All screen shots are taken from the copy of ISO-32000-1 that is provided by Adobe on its web site.)

**Update:**

If you want to add a link to a remote page, you can also follow the example on page 197-198 of [iText in Action - Second Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book): see the [LinkActions](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=131) example that uses the [gotoRemotePage()](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfAction.html) method.

Internally, this method looks like this:

```
public static PdfAction gotoRemotePage(String filename, String dest, boolean isName, boolean newWindow) {
    PdfAction action = new PdfAction();
    action.put(PdfName.F, new PdfString(filename));
    action.put(PdfName.S, PdfName.GOTOR);
    if (isName)
        action.put(PdfName.D, new PdfName(dest));
    else
        action.put(PdfName.D, new PdfString(dest, PdfObject.TEXT_UNICODE));
    if (newWindow)
        action.put(PdfName.NEWWINDOW, PdfBoolean.PDFTRUE);
    return action;
}
```

Note that this assumes that you have a named destination in the target file.

I think that you'd rather want to use the constructor that takes a page number:

```
public PdfAction(String filename, int page) {
    put(PdfName.S, PdfName.GOTOR);
    put(PdfName.F, new PdfString(filename));
    put(PdfName.D, new PdfLiteral("[" + (page - 1) + " /FitH 10000]"));
}
```

Of course, this doesn't use `PdfName.FIT`. If you really want to define the destination yourself, you need a line that looks like this:

```
put(PdfName.D, new PdfLiteral("[" + (page - 1) + " /Fit]"));
```

Comment: I have tried this chunk.setAction(PdfAction.gotoRemotePage(filepath,"1", false, true));

Comment: That's indeed easier than trying to construct the `PdfAction` *manually*. I'll add a pointer to the official documentation where the method is described.

Comment: I don't think you understand what you're doing. If "1" is a named destination in your target PDF, you know what you're doing. If "1" is a page number, then you haven't read my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer once more to show why you aren't interpreting the API documentation correctly.